# How does VBA rand generate random numbers using the upperbound and lowerbound?

Tags: vba, excel, random

so maybe this is redundant, maybe it's like asking why most humans are born with 5 fingers, the short answer in the end is always: because that's how it is and it just works, but I hate that answer and dammit I want to know how Rnd() function in VBA works.

The MSDN for Ms Office Excel says that RND is defined as:

`Rnd[(number)] 'The optional number argument is a Single or any valid numeric expression.`

It goes on to say

> "The value of number determines how Rnd generates a random number: For
>   any given initial seed, the same number sequence is generated because
>   each successive call to the Rnd function uses the previous number as a
>   seed for the next number in the sequence."

followed by this:

> To produce random integers in a given range, use this formula:
>
> `Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)`

so for example:
`Dim MyValue
MyValue = Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)    ' Generate random value between 1 and 6.`

But how does that work? where are these numbers coming from? why does `6 * Rnd + 1` get you random number between 1 and 6, but `6 * Rnd + 5` gets you a number between 5 and 10?

furthermore, if it was so apparent to the creators of VBA what formula to use to successfully narrow this down to a specific range, why not just have the RND function come with optional Ubound and Lbound arguments? I can't be the only one looking at that formula going what in the world is that?

At the end of the day it works of course fine for any of my pseudo random number needs and maybe I'm looking a gift horse in the mouth but still!

---

EDIT

---

It occurs to me that this question might be based in Math itself. if you take a small integer what functions do you apply to make that integer fit in a specified range.. so can anyone explain how this formula works?

Comment: The constant "+1" in the original formula given needs to be 0.5 (0.499999 repeating, but w/e) How has nobody mentioned this yet? Or prove me wrong? Using +1 can cause you to round OVER your upperbound.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a step by step guide:

1. `Rnd` gives a random decimal between 0 and < 1
2. `6 * Rnd` gives a random decimal between 0 and < 6
3. `Int(6 * Rnd)` round it *down* so you get a random value between 0 and 5

It's very common to generate a random number between a lower and upper bound. Excel does have a `RANDBETWEEN` function to do this:

```
Value = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)
```

---

**Edit:** now let's fit that into `Lbound` and `Ubound` (assuming both are integers and `Lbound < Ubound`)

First, define:

```
n = ubound - lbound
```

Next, we will rewrite the MSDN formula slightly:

```
   Int((ubound - lbound + 1) * Rnd + lbound)
== Int((ubound - lbound + 1) * Rnd) + lbound
== Int(((n + 1) * Rnd)              + lbound
```

From #3, we know that `Int(((n + 1) * Rnd)` gives a random integer between 0 and n. So when you add that random number to the lowerbound, you get a number between the lowerbound and the upperbound;

```
   Int(((n + 1) * Rnd) + lbound
== 0...n               + lbound
== lbound...ubound
```

Comment: so it seems to me, the formula could be `Int(Ubound * Rnd + Lbound) `

Comment: That only works if your `LBound` is 0 or 1. Try generating a random number between 5 and 10

Comment: so how do those numbers work? why is it `ubound - lbound + 1`? I sorta get it if you take your ubound and * RND() then you're gonna get a number between 0 and whatever that is. but then, how does the Lbound figure into that?

Answer (score 2):

This may make it a bit more clear: Rnd returns a random number in 0 to <1 range (it is a Single -- aka a fraction, so you have all kinds of 0.3948, 0.001, 0.8, etc. -- uniformly distributed pseudo random numbers). The argument in the function is intended for "ease of use" in formulas and algorithms, but arguably not a good fit for a casual user.

In general, Rnd actually follows a de-facto standard of how random number generator API is exposed in many, if not all programming languages (i.e. generating a random fraction from 0.0 to <1.0). So if you go from VBA to Python to Java to C -- you'll see a striking resemblance in terms of how it works.

Having said that, many languages (for example, Python) provide higher level wrappers to the core Rnd function so it will be easier to use in basic scenarios. VBA is a pretty old language -- one that is rarely updated by Microsoft (it is a blessing and a curse), so if you need a helper function you'd have to do it yourself.

Here what you can use instead:

```
Function RndBetween(lowerbound As Int, upperbound As Int) As Int
    RndBetween = Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
End Function
```

And in your code it becomes simple:

```
RndBetween(1, 6)
```

After some time you'll have a module of the helper functions that will make life easier and code much more readable. Until then... StackOverflow :-)

Comment: Good info to know, interesting, but it still doesn't help with where the numbers in the helper came from. I've done a lot of coding and am definitely familiar with helpers to shorten methods, But I'd still like to know where the + this - That * and - come from. I can't figure out how that works.

Comment: @user1759942 Well, but that's just math. If you substitute variable names for x, y, z etc... and write it on a sheet of paper as a formula -- you might have a better visual than VBA code. It is hard to read as is. It may also help to print numerical representation for a few instances in the console - just to see how it gets calculated.

Answer (score 1):

using the formula like RndBetween like `make_random_old = CLng((up - down + 1) * Rnd + down)`

It is extremely wrong (30 minutes debugging of my life was the price to understand it!) :)

You can check why, using the Sub TestMe here:

```
Public Sub testme()

    Dim l_counter       As Long
    Dim l_random        As Long

    For l_counter = 0 To 10000
        l_random = make_random_old(0, 2)
        If l_random = 3 Then Debug.Print l_random
    Next l_counter

    Debug.Print "END"

End Sub

Public Function make_random(down As Long, up As Long) As Long

    make_random = CLng((up - down + 1) * Rnd + down)

    If make_random > up Then make_random = up
    If make_random < down Then make_random = down

End Function

Public Function make_random_old(down As Long, up As Long) As Long

    make_random_old = CLng((up - down + 1) * Rnd + down)

End Function
```

As a workaround for some random in RndBetweem, use `make_random` - the second function in the code. 
It will save you lots of problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

@Code Different has the correct answer already.This is just for people who don't get it on the first glance

1. Excel only generates a random number between 0 to 1
2. By multiplying the random number generated in step 1 by a number `x` we can get a value between `0` and `x`

So how does

`Int ((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)`

generate a random number between upper and lower bound

3. In the last step you provided the number `x` to which the random number generated in step 1 was multiplied.Here,to generate this number `x` you do `upperbound - lowerbound` so that a `random_number` from `0` to the difference of two numbers i.e (`upperbound - lowerbound`) is produced.Now if you add the smaller number i.e. `lowerbound` to `random_number` it will generate a sum greater than the `lowerbound` & lesser than `upperbound`