# Randomising a single column in excel multiple times

Tags: excel, vba

I want to randomise a column of data in excel and then populate a new column with this  randomised data. i.e. I want to randomise the contents of column B and then paste the results into column C but multiple times (100+).

I have yet to learn VBA but I imagine there is some code that would achieve this?

Comment: How to loop: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

Comment: How to produce a random number: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335166/how-does-vba-rand-generate-random-numbers-using-the-upperbound-and-lowerbound

Comment: That should get you started.  Once you have some code of your own, if you get stuck, edit your original question and include the code you've created and the specific problem you're running into and we can help you from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No VBA is required for this.  Say we have data from **B1** through **B22**.  In **A1** enter:

```
=RAND()
```

and copy downwards.  In **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(LARGE($A$1:$A$22,ROWS($1:1)),$A$1:$A$22,0))
```

and copy downwards.  Each time the worksheet is re-calculated, a new "shuffle" will appear in column **C**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is great. I have dragged this out to produce many columns of random data and have turned off automatic calculations for now.

Comment: @CharlieRoper  Thank you for the feedback.